# google maps geocoder - point on a street

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

If I use google maps geocoder to find a point of an address - I usually get a point in the middle of the building (roof top)

example:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=350+Alabama+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA,+United+States&hl=en&ll=37.764842,-122.412077&spn=0.001497,0.002661&sll=37.794661,-122.425718&sspn=0.001496,0.002661&oq=350%2BAlabama%2BStreet&hnear=350+Alabama+St,+San+Francisco,+California+94110&t=m&z=19

Geocoder request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=350+Alabama+Street+San+Francisco&sensor=false

so the point is actually in the middle of Harrison and Alabama streets

But I need to get a point that is located on Alabama street line

Is there a ways to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may request the directionsService instead of geocoding, this should return a location placed on the street when used with `google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING`

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=350+Alabama+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA,+United+States&daddr=Alabama+St&hl=en&sll=37.764829,-122.412369&sspn=0.001043,0.002411&geocode=Fco-QAIdXiG0-ClZY3r_L36PgDG0YXVKn8-9fQ%3BFe4-QAIdrCK0-A&oq=350+Alabama+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA,+United+States&mra=dme&mrsp=1&sz=19&t=m&z=19

Comment: I have the opposite problem - how do I request the geocoder API/Google Maps return a rootop point instead of a street point? My test address: 3433 Roberto Ct, 93401 used to return a point on the building but now returns a point in the street.

Comment: the term "ROOFTOP" when used with the geocoder means a precise result, not a real rooftop. There is no option to specify that the geocoder should retrn a location on a building, street or somewhere else.

Comment: Note that in the past the "rooftop" results did indeed place the pin on a building. The same query/api call today places the pin in the street but it still says quality is rooftop. This may be just in my area (93401.) I switched o the Bing API which returns both types of points.